# Symfony2 error: Unknown database

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a db that I'm calling "my_db". I'm trying to connect to it with Symfony2, but it keeps telling me this:

> "Unknown database: "MY_DB"

What I did:

1. First I tried to modify the `config.yml`, and `parameters.yml`, to change the db name, since it seems to be in capitals in the error and the db name really isn't. The name in the `config.yml` was already in lowercase, but in `parameters.yml`(which I don't even use for this) it was in capitals. I changed it to make sure, but nope.. Nothing. Still same error. And yes, I cleared the cache.
2. Then I changed the actual mysql-database name to uppercase in phpmyadmin: "my_db" to "MY_DB", and tadaa: it worked!

> Wait But Why?

There is something I'm missing here, since the names are all correct in the settings, but the problem didn't go away until I changed the database name to match the name in the error.

First it didn't work and I didn't know why. Now it works and I don't know why.

I need to know why this happens, so that nothing weird happens when I go to production later.

Comment: No more details in the logs files?

Comment: Nope. Nada. That's all there was in any log. RabbitMq makes the logging go weird, and it points the error to the rabbitmq related files, not the real ones. But the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of Symfony or Doctrine, it's a problem at the database level, somehow your database is case sensitive, I think there's a way to change that by setting the `lower_case_table_names` system variable, read more about it here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: I don't get it. I'm trying to connect to "my_db", and the error states that there is no "MY_DB", because there isn't. The actual database name is in lowercase: "my_db". I don't understand where the error gets the "MY_DB" -name, since all the names everywhere are in lowercase. Is there something happening behind the curtains here?